# Why tf.keras.optimizers.SGD has no global_step

Tags: tensorflow

In TF 1.14, below code will raise exception.

```
 optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=params['lr'])
 train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss, global_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())
```

The exception is

```
TypeError: minimize() got an unexpected keyword argument 'global_step'
```

It seems that `tf.keras.optimizers` in unavailable in TF 1.14. However, why the `global_step` is gone in tf.keras.optimizers.SGD? It is supposed to be there in `tf.train.Optimizer` of TF 1.14

Answer (score 0):

`tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer` and `tf.train.Optimizer` are two distinct classes. There was never `global_step` in `tf.keras.optimizers.Optimizer`